# Processes communicating through named shared memory

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I made 2 Visual Studio projects that communicate through a mapped file. But I have to start each of them sepparately: First start A, run it (it will create the mapped file and fill it with info). Then I have to start B, which will read the file and print whatever is in it. Of course, closing A and running B will not work(B will not find the mapped file since that one is in the memory only while A is running).

My question is: is there a way to start my project B through A, without me needing to run project B manually?

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx  It is the windows equivalent of exec or system.

Comment: The example is not really clear to me. Should I give the path of my .cpp file?

Comment: To be safe, give it the full path.  If you execute a.exe from explorer, it doesn't always know where the current working directory is so it can pick b.exe from anywhere, especially if there is a chdir somewhere in your code before you call CreateProcess.  You can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963(v=vs.85).aspx to get the full path name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of starting manually A and then B you should only start manually program A and let program A start program B with the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
STARTUPINFO startupinfo ;
startupinfo.cb = sizeof (startupinfo) ;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pinfo ;
memset(&startupinfo, 0, sizeof (startupinfo)) ;
bool success = CreateProcess("b.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, false, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                             NULL, NULL, &startupinfo, &pinfo) ;
```

Comment: And where should I put my program B? Or how do I pass it as argument to the CreateProcess function?

Comment: You put A.exe and B.exe into the same folder. In A.exe you start B.exe with `CreateProcess`. Just wait a bit, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thought I could put the B.cpp file and it would run. Is there a way to have it this way?

Comment: You cannot run a .cpp file, you can only compile it. You can only rubn .exe files.